# Looking for 1986 book "Algebraic and topological theories"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, books

I am looking for the proceedings book (in paper or electronic form):

**Algebraic and topological theories**, Papers from the symposium dedicated to the memory of Dr. Takehiko Miyata held in Kinosaki, October 30- November 9, 1984. Editors : Nagata, Araki, Hattori, Iwahori.
(English) Zbl 0782.00082. Tokyo: Kinokuniya Company Ltd. vii, 660 p. (1986).

Apparently it is present only in two libraries in Europe (one in Poland and one in Germany) and for some unknown reason the inter library loan won't work. (I just received the negative answers.) Does anyone on MO know where and how I can get it ? An electronic copy would be perfect of course. Note that I am especially interested in the paper of Kambayashi, *Nori’s construction of Galois coverings in positive characteristics* but other articles in the proceedings also (so ideally I'd like to get my hands on the whole book).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try asking your Japanese colleagues?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just sent an email to T. Kambayashi (but I think he's retired).

Answer (score 3):

It has been digitized by [the Hathitrust library](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924052933110), but they only provide limited search capabilities because of copyright restrictions. The [British Library](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?fn=search&ct=search&vid=BLVU1&vl(freeText0)=4875730985) will send you a pdf if you pay the copyright fee of £ 39. You could try this if all else fails.

[image]